# Use of unresolved identifier "performSegue" error

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, segue

Why does Xcode tell me that performSegue(withIdentifier:) is an unresolved identifier? (Please see commented out line)

```
import UIKit

class AllListsViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = makeCell(for: tableView)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "List \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChecklist", sender: nil) // Use of unresolved identifier "performSegue"
}

func makeCell(for tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) {
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated your code with proper indenting. The error is very clear now.

Comment: @NiravD There is no extra `}`. See the code with proper indenting.

Comment: @NiravD, you´re almost right, it´s not an extra `{` but it´s in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

You have a two errors in your code:

1. Line 27 `}` shall be at the end since this ends the class
2. You´re inheriting from `UITableViewController`, so you need to `override` `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

Code that compiles:

```
import UIKit

class AllListsViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = makeCell(for: tableView)
        cell.textLabel!.text = "List \(indexPath.row)"

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowChecklist", sender: nil) // Use of unresolved identifier "performSegue"
    }

    func makeCell(for tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
        if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) {
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try including `UIViewController` to the class, that fixed my issue:

```
class AllListsViewController: UITableViewController, UIViewController { 
                                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```